# Enthought canopy upgrade python version

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, canopy

I am currently running enthaught canopy's python version 2.7.11 on laptop however my desktop has the latest python version 3.5.2 how do i update the same in my laptop?
What commands should i run or am i required to re un nstall and re install canopy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current version of Canopy is 2.1.3, supporting Python 2.7.13 and 3.5.2 (and 3.6 with an an extra step).

To update Canopy, please see ["Installing a new Canopy version"](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469570-Installing-a-new-Canopy-version).

(Yes, you'll need to uninstall Canopy v1.x before installing Canopy 2)